# Compute Engine Backup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backup

I've two VMs created at the Compute Engine session with hourly snapshot as backup copies. I never created any storage bucket, I wonder where do those snapshots stored and how does it count for the storage space charges?

And, is there a way I can backup the VMs to on-prem storage?  e.g. can I use any API command to download the VM snapshot to my local storage as a backup of backup just in case Google Cloud screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a snapshot, you can specify a [storage location](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#default_location). The location of a snapshot affects its availability and can incur networking costs when creating the snapshot or restoring it to a new disk. You will find the pricing for snapshot storage [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing#persistentdisk).

[This article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#export_an_image_to_google_cloud_storage) describes how to create an image from your VM's root disk and export it to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview) or you can directly download it to your remote computer.